# Getting the RFID card UID value without SPI

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

As I am using arduino along with several sensors like ultrasonic sensor and esp8266 - 01 (wifi module). Using SPI.h (header) is making some trouble. I confirmed that this is the line of code causing trouble. Is there any way to get around it and find the UID value?

Comment: Please show the error and the code producing it. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to make a [Miminal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

U can try using [PN532](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532/tree/master/PN532_SPI).It is available in the libraries(manage libraries) of he arduino.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, The PN532 you mentioned, will it work for RFID, everywhere in there I see NFC..